# MySQL database normalization (taken from Excel)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I have imported a SQL database from an Excel sheet, so it's a little bit messy. For example there's a `product` field with `VARCHAR` values such as `product8`. I would like to grep through these data using some regex, capture the `id` in this example, and alter column data types. As of now I would start `preg_match`ing the long and hard PHP way, and I'm curious how a database normalization is done right using SQL commands. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: SQL does have regex too ;)  But I think you confuse the term normalization. Normalization is structuring the datamodel such that all data is functionally dependent on the primary keys. In general reducing redundancy in data.

Answer (score 1):

you can select case, to pull the ids

```
select right(product,length(product)-7) as productID from table
```

this will pull the numbers, then you can do whatever

Comment: I would be interested in how to capture that ID using regular expressions. cuz I could apply that to the rest of the fields, which are much worse than this one.